# Something is moving my drop down nav bar to the right

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the html section the html & css nav option is moved to the right for some reason, how do I get it to align with the other nav options.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEqPRQ

```
#nav {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.250em 0 1.250em 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-size: 106.25%;
  font-family: 'Oxygen';
}

#nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

#nav ul li ul.dropdown {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: auto;
  left: 400;
  vertical-align: left;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
}

#nav ul li ul.dropdown li {
  display: block;
}

#nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2%;
  padding: 4.375em 1.250em 4.375em 1.250em;
}

#nav > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

#nav > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #00c5a2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<ul>` has a default styling (`padding-left`) which has to be removed. Adding

```
#nav ul li ul.dropdown {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

moves your text to the left.

You should also check your CSS, `vertical-align: left` and `left: 400` (doesn't have a unit) aren't valid and won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `.dropdown` style as follows:

```
#nav ul li ul.dropdown {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: auto;
  left: 0;
  vertical-align: left;
}
```

Then the parent `li` position to relative:

```
#nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding: 4.375em 1.250em 4.375em 1.250em;
  position: relative;
}
```

This ensures the dropdown always positions itself absolute to its parent (the `li`).

Also adding `padding: 0` to the `dropdown ul`:

```
#nav ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/04zospoj/

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem adding padding left = 0 in the css of #nav ul li ul.dropdown :

```
#nav ul li ul.dropdown {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```